# XSLT transformation based on attribute value not executing

Tags: xml, xslt, sparql

I'm trying to perform an XSLT transformation of an autogenerated XML file. I mention autogenerated because this means I (most likely) cannot change the structure of the XML. In the code snippet below, I have (manually) added a single line to the XML, referencing my XSL file.

Hoping to achieve a table view in the client browser, loaded with data from the XML file. Am also open to suggestions for methods other than XSLT for going about this.

Summary: I wish to produce a table with columns like Year, Chapter, Number and Name. These are found in an XML file under `/sparql/results/result`, then a tag like `<binding name='Year'><literal>2018</literal></binding>` (and so forth for the other column names). Put short, I need to reference `/sparql/results/result/binding[@name='Year']/literal` into the table.

Unfortunately, this does not work as I had expected it to. Granted, it's been about ten years since I worked with XSLT so I may miss something.

EDIT: I should clarify "does not work as expected" as "IE11 (sorry, work...) only shows the XML source data, not the transformed HTML view. Firefox and Edge behave the same. Company workstations so unable to update browser or install any add-ons."

Any help on getting this to work is most appreciated.

Minimum sample for data.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="rbv.xsl"?>
<sparql xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#'>
    <head>
        <variable name='Year'/>
        <variable name='Chapter'/>
        <variable name='Number'/>
        <variable name='Name'/>
        <variable name='Value'/>
    </head>
    <results>
        <result>
            <binding name='Year'>
                <literal datatype='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#gYear'>2018</literal>
            </binding>
            <binding name='Number'>
                <literal>1</literal>
            </binding>
            <binding name='Chapter'>
                <literal>ABC</literal>
            </binding>
            <binding name='Value'>
                <literal datatype='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#decimal'>0</literal>
            </binding>
            <binding name='Name'>
                <literal>foo</literal>
            </binding>
        </result>
        <result>
            <binding name='Year'>
                <literal datatype='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#gYear'>2018</literal>
            </binding>
            <binding name='Number'>
                <literal>13</literal>
            </binding>
            <binding name='Chapter'>
                <literal>XYZ</literal>
            </binding>
            <binding name='Value'>
                <literal datatype='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#decimal'>0</literal>
            </binding>
            <binding name='Name'>
                <literal>bar</literal>
            </binding>
        </result>
    </results>
</sparql>
```

Minimum sample for rbv.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Sample RBV tabel</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Sample RBV tabel</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Jaar</th>
        <th>Hoofdstuk</th>
        <th>Artikel</th>
        <th>Naam</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="sparql/results/result">
        <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="binding[@name='Year']/literal"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="binding[@name='Chapter']/literal"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="binding[@name='Number']/literal"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="binding[@name='Name']/literal"/></td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The `xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#'` puts your XML elements into that namespace and you need to adapt the XSLT to take the namespace into acount. That has not changed in ten years unless you move to XSLT 2 or 3, usually outside of the browser, where you can use `xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#'"`. What has changed is that Firefox now, like Chrome, does not load `xm-stylesheet` referenced XSLT if you load the XML from the file system.

Comment: would it not be "easier" to use some other SPARQL resultset format like CSV, TSV or JSON?

Answer (score 0):

**use namespace**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ab="http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#" exclude-result-prefixes="ab">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Sample RBV tabel</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h2>Sample RBV tabel</h2>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                        <th>Jaar</th>
                        <th>Hoofdstuk</th>
                        <th>Artikel</th>
                        <th>Naam</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="ab:sparql/ab:results/ab:result">
                        <tr>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="ab:binding[@name='Year']/ab:literal"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="ab:binding[@name='Chapter']/ab:literal"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="ab:binding[@name='Number']/ab:literal"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="ab:binding[@name='Name']/ab:literal"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```